# Can't find variable: style in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import react from "react"
import {View, Text, Image, StyleSheet, TouchableOpacity} from 'react-native'
import { Divider } from 'react-native-elements'

const postFooterIcons = [
   {
       name:'Like',
       ImageUrl:'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/b/facebook-like-vector-icon-white-background-128850059.jpg',
    },
   {
       name:'Comment',
       ImageUrl:'https://uxwing.com/wp-content/themes/uxwing/download/37-communication-chat-call/comment.png',
   },
   {
       name:'Share',
       ImageUrl:'https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/2036/PNG/512/sharing_share_icon_124236.png',
   },
   {
       name:'Save',
       ImageUrl:'https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSvRw8IyLCFaN6nK4G1nWzEy0P4MKHIEbLO5Re7LgXYcOHC0JlKfp3kLq7eyorVOqknEtA&usqp=CAU',
   },
]

const Post = ({post}) => {
   return(
       <View style={{ marginBottom:30}}>
           <Divider width={1} orientation='vertical' />
           <PostHeader post={post}/>
           <PostImage post={post}/> 
           <View style={{marginHorizontal:15, marginTop: 10}}> 
               <PostFooter />
           </View>
        </View>
   )
}

const PostHeader = ({post}) => (
   <View 
       style={{
           flexDirection: 'row', 
           justifyContent:'space-between', 
           margin:5, 
           alignItems:'center'}}>
       
       <View style={{ flexDirection : 'row', alignItems:'center'}}>
          <Image source={{ uri: post.profile_picture }} style={styles.story} />
          <Text style={{ color: 'white', marginLeft: 5, fontWeight:'700'}}>
           {post.user}   
           </Text>
       </View>

       <Text style={{color:'white', fontWeight:'900'}}>...</Text>
    </View>     
)

const PostImage = ({post}) => (
   <View
       style={{
           width: '100%',
           height: 450,
       }}> 
   <Image 
   source={{ uri: 'https://img.chuing.net/i/QQNVupN/Ash_Pignite.png' }} 
   style={{height:'100%', resizeMode:'cover'}} />  
   </View>  
  
)

const PostFooter = () =>  {
    <Icon imgStyle={style.footerIcon} imgUrl={postFooterIcons[0].ImageUrl} /> 
   }


const Icon = ({imgStyle, imgUrl}) => (
   <TouchableOpacity>
       <Image style={imgStyle} source={{ uri: imgUrl}} /> 
   </TouchableOpacity>
)

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
   story:{
       width: 35,
       height: 35,
       borderRadius : 50,
       marginleft:6,
       borderwidth:1.6,
       borderColor: '#ff8501',
   },

   footerIcon : {
       width: 33,
       height: 33,
   }
})



export default Post
```

i get an error that

ReferenceError: Can't find variable: style

This error is located at:
in PostFooter (created by Post)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Post)
in RCTView (created by View)
in View (created by Post)

what is wrong in my code.. please help me
the debugger told me that "Can't find variable: style"

Comment: It's the `style.footerIcon` in PostFooter.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo, in
`<Icon imgStyle={style.footerIcon} imgUrl={postFooterIcons[0].ImageUrl} />` It should be `styles.footerIcon`

Since the variable where you hold your styles is called `styles` the code fails cause you are currently looking for `style`